# Dojox Mobile Scrollable View - Disable Scroll

Tags: dojo, dojox.mobile

I have a dojox-mobile-scrollable view list which can be scrolled by default.
I need to disable the scroll when I am performing a swipe operation on the list items inside it.

How to **disable** the scroll in a Scrollable View?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set myScrollableView.disableTouchScroll = true, it should do the trick.